# Ethernet over IP

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ethernet, tunneling

I need to merge two L2 broadcast domain into single domain and I have to do this over unmanaged by me L3 IP network.

All that I could find is vtun utility for linux.

Which software&howto you can suggest?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Create a VPN between the two networks. Use `brctl` to bridge the vpn and ethernet interfaces on each side.

Comment: Found brctl in bridge-utils, will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

What type of connections are you trying to merge? Is this for two directly attached networks (say a multihomed Linux box) or is this two remote networks?

You might check out L2TP (Layer 2 tunneling protocol) which is commonly used with IPSec VPNs

http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/freeswan-l2tp.html

http://linuxexplore.com/how-tos/l2tp-vpn-using-xl2tpd/

-jkm